# recursive function called with different values

Tags: java, recursion

I have a recursive function like this:

```
public static int h(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        //variable value is a fixed one.
        i = value % 2;
        return h(n - h(i) - 1) + h(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Suppose the value of variable `value` is even at this time.Then if I call the function with `h(12)`  I want to know how the function works?

In this case what I want to happen is evaluate
`h(12)=h[12-h(0)-1]+h(10)

     =h(11)+h(10) 
     ={h(11-h(0)-1)+h(9)}+{h(10-h(0)-1)+h(8)}
     ={h(10)+h(9)}+{h(9)+h(8)}`

Here when evaluating `h(11)+h(10)` does the function first finish `h(11)` and get a value for that before starting with `h(n-2)` which is this case `h(10)`.

If it first finish `h(11)` then finally it has to reach n==0 or n==1 case.Then by the time it reaches wouldn't `h(n-2)` be `h(-2)` or `h(-1)`.
How can I store the initial function call value of 12 and when it reaches `h(n-2)` to call as `h(10)` and then make that part to evaluate as h(8),h(6)..

Comment: Don't think of recursion as something special; it works just like any other function call.

Answer (score 2):

Each function call stores its own copy of arguments. So, call to `h(11)` won't change `n` in the first call (`h(12)`).

Expressions in Java are evaluated from left to right. This means that the call `h(11)` would finish before `h(10)` is called from `h(12)`. However, in this case this is not important, since the result would be the same either way.

Comment: :  Thanks for the answer.If I want to change the statement  `(h(n-h(i)-1)+h(n-2))` to `(h(n-h(i)-1)+h(n-2))+3` how can i change it.The problem is say if I initially want to evaluate `h(4)`.Then `(h(n-h(i)-1)+h(n-2))`would give 0.Then for that answer I want to add 3.But if i change the statement to `(h(n-h(i)-1)+h(n-2))+3` every time the function is recursively called a 3 is added giving me 12.How can I stop this and make the function so that after evaluating `(h(n-h(i)-1)+h(n-2))` it adds 3 to the result of  `(h(n-h(i)-1)+h(n-2))`